# Understanding 2nd Normalized Form

Tags: mysql, database-normalization

I am trying to understand 2nd normalized form. I understand 1NF form and 3NF form, but I don't quite understand 2NF form.

I am going to explain the scenario I have created to try and understand below and if something is not clear, let me know and I will clarify it for you.

Here is my table in 1NF form:

```
create table testing.item_order_1nf (

    call_date date,
    first_name varchar(255),
    last_name varchar(255),
    street_address varchar(255),
    city varchar(255),
    state char(2),
    zip_code char(5),
    home_phone_number char(11),
    mobile_phone_number char(11),
    other_phone_number varchar(255),
    quantity smallint,
    item_name varchar(255),
    item_description varchar(255),
    unit_price decimal(4,2),
    handling_notes varchar(255),
    item_order_id smallint,
    customer_id smallint,
    item_id tinyint,

    primary key(item_order_id, item_id)

)
```

Reason for primary key: The same item_order_id can appear multiple times. It appears 1 time for every item that appears on that order. If one order contains 3 items, the order_id will appear 3 times.

Here is what I have when I try to convert from 1 table in 1NF form to 3 tables in 2NF form:

```
create table testing.customers (

    customer_id smallint,
    first_name varchar(255),
    last_name varchar(255),
    street_address varchar(255),
    city varchar(255),
    state char(2),
    zip_code char(5),
    home_phone_number char(11),
    mobile_phone_number char(11),
    other_phone_number varchar(25),

    primary key (customer_id)

),


create table testing.items (

    item_id tinyint,
    item_name varchar(255),
    item_description varchar(255),
    item_price decimal(4,2),

    primary key (item_id)

),


create table testing.item_orders (

    item_order_id smallint,
    item_id tinyint,
    customer_id smallint,
    handling_notes varchar(255),
    order_date date,
    quantity smallint,

    primary key (item_order_id),
    foreign key (item_id) references testing.items(item_id),
    foreign key (customer_id) references testing.customers(customer_id)

)
```

Does this look okay? If not, what did I do incorrectly?

**Edit #1:**

1. Explanation for testing.customers: Every column is dependent on the customer_id value and only the customer_id value.
2. Explanation for testing.items: The item_name, item_description, and item_price are dependent on what the item_id value is.
3. Explanation for testing.item_orders: Multiple items can appear on the same order. Also, I included the item_id and customer_id so I could relate this table to the other two tables in a join. The handling_notes and order_date are dependent on the order, although I don't know where else I could place the order_date.

**Edit #2:**

An argument could be made where the city, state, and zipcode are not dependent on the customer_id, because multiple customers could have the same values for all 3 of those, so if I was going to make an edit, it would be something like this:

```
create table testing.customers (

        customer_id smallint,
        first_name varchar(255),
        last_name varchar(255),
        street_address varchar(255),
        home_phone_number char(11),
        mobile_phone_number char(11),
        other_phone_number varchar(25),

        primary key (customer_id)

    )

create table testing.item_orders (

    item_order_id smallint,
    item_id tinyint,
    customer_id smallint,
    city varchar(255),
    state char(2),
    zip_code char(5),
    handling_notes varchar(255),
    order_date date,
    quantity smallint,

    primary key (item_order_id),
    foreign key (item_id) references testing.items(item_id),
    foreign key (customer_id) references testing.customers(customer_id)

)
```

**Edit #3:** Add clarification

When I was trying to create a scenario, my thought process was as follows: customer places an order and generates a item_order_id value. On this item_order, the item_id value appears one time for each type of item ordered.

Example: I place an order. My order id is #123. On my order I buy 1 chair, 1 book, 1 plant, 3 sodas.

My results would look like this:

```
item_order_id     item_name     quantity

123     chair     1

123     book     1

123     plant     1

123     soda     3
```

Comment: You seem to assume that `item_order_id` uniquely defines the `item`, but I guess that `item_order_id` only uniquely defines a *set* of items for a certain customer. Can you elaborate on what `item_order_id` is the unique `id` of?

Comment: When I was trying to create a scenario, my thought process was a customer places an order and generates a item_order_id value. On this item_order, the item_id value appears one time for each type of item ordered. Does that help?

Comment: Hi. Normalization to higher NFs uses FDs that hold in the original. But you don't mention them. So you are not telling us enough info to check your work. Explain how you produced those components. Also PKs don't matter, CKs do. PS Clarify via post edits, not comments.

Comment: I'll edit my post in just a second, can you clarify the shorthand for me? NF = Normalized form, but what is FD, and CKs?

Comment: FD = functional dependency, CK = candidate key. Your post does not describe a process of normalization. Also you still haven't given your initial FDs and, if they weren't given to you & you had to propose some, your justification for them. Please give your textbook name & edition and show your work following it. PS Please do not edit by appending EDITs, edit your post to be the best presentation. Adding to something unclear does not make it clear.

Comment: Database Administration: The complete guide to DBA Practices and Procedures 2nd edition. I am just trying to understand how 2NF works.

Comment: "An argument could be made where the city, state, and zipcode are not dependent on the customer_id, because multiple customers could have the same values for all 3 of those" doesn't make sense; if X determines Y then two X values can appear with the same Y value. (But each X value can only appear with a single Y value.)

Comment: Please reread & act on my comments.

Comment: "To transform 1 NF data into 2NF, create separate entities for sets of attributes that apply to multiple records and assign a foreign key to the new entity to relate it to its previous entity. Entity occurrences should not depend on anything other than the entity's primary key."

Comment: That quote came directly from my book, word for word. I will edit my post in a second to explain the functional dependencies and candidate keys.

Comment: "If X determines Y then two X values can appear with the same Y value. (But each X value can only appear with a single Y value.)"  Part of the criteria for 2NF is that every non-key attribute is fully dependent on the key. The City, State, and Zip code are not fully dependent on the customer_id value because each x (city, state, or zip code) can be long to multiple y values (customer_id). That is what I meant.

Comment: That "because" doesn't make sense. Read the definition of when a FD holds. Which does not involve NFs. Find out what partial & full FDs are. You are not applying definitions correctly. Also PKs don't matter, CKs do (there can be more than one).

Comment: "Full Functional Dependency: in a relation, there exists full functional dependency between two attributes X and Y, when X is functionally dependent on Y and is not functionally dependent on any proper subset of Y. Partial Functional Dependency: In a relation, there exists partial dependency when a non prime attribute (the attributes which are not part of any candidate key) is functionally dependent on a proper subset of Candidate key. Candidate key: column or set of columns in a table that can uniquely identify any database record without referring to any other data."

Comment: I appreciate your help btw, I'm just trying to understand :)

Comment: An FD is from a set of attributes to a set of attributes or to an attribute; so that full FD definition is misleading. A partial FD is one that is not full; that definition of partial FD is wrong. That definition of CK is a mess & ignoring the mess it is a definition of superkey, not CK. See some other textbooks, dozens are free online in pdf. (But many are, like yours, sloppy & otherwise poor.)

Comment: Instead of quoting definitions or insulting what book I'm using at me, can you explain to me why my logic regarding city, state, and zip code is incorrect? Clearly database administration is something I am lacking knowledge in.